# x11vnc : how to have the login screen?

Tags: display-manager, x11vnc

I use [x11vnc](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/) since long, to connect from my office to my home. My goal is to access to my computer exactly as if I were in front of it. So when I return to home I can continue was I started remotely, and vice-versa.
The problem is I must leave my X session open before going to work, because x11vnc don't allow me to see any login screen. So I can't reboot remotely, I can't log as another user, etc.

Is there any way to have this login screen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

x11vnc perfectly works with `x11vnc -display :0 -auth guess -no6 -forever -nolookup -passwd xxxx -ping 60`
Also have a look at the `-reopen` parameter in case of problem when you logoff.

I use KDM so I put this line into `/etc/kde/kdm/Xsetup`

Every needed informations are there : http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/faq.html

Answer (score 3):

If you'd like the graphical login screen then install a **Desktop Manager** such as `GDM`, `KDM`, `LXDM`, `SLIM`, `Qingy`, `LightDM`, `WDM` (I'm sure there are many others, but these are all that I could rattle off the top of my head).

Once installed, enable it start **at boot**. The procedure for enabling this to start at boot will depend on your distribution's init system (sysvinit/systemd).

Instructions to enabling things to run at boot will most likely be explained on your distribution's wiki page.

- **sysvinit** is configured via /etc/rc.conf
- **systemd** requires the use of systemd unit files

***Remember***: You will also need to make sure that x11vnc is loaded at boot, and loaded after the Desktop Manager. Once that's all setup you *should* be able to reboot the machine remotely.

Good luck.